# How do I package and consume my node native extension?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I've built my first node native extension and want to consume it in another node app, but I don't know which files need to be packaged up nor how they should be packaged for distribution & consumption by other apps.

In the "build/release" directory of my extension project there's "mylib.lib", "mylib.node", and "mylib.exp".  Is "mylib.node" the only file to be published and consumed by the app?

Presumably not, as the root level of my extension project contains "package.json" and I thought that was required for NPM.  But I don't want them to have to build/compile so I may need a completely different package.json for distribution vs. development?